# Combine string in objectivec

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

How do I concenate 2 strings in objective-c, like in VB.net you can just do "foo" & "bar"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
NSString *newString = [@"foo" stringByAppendingString:@"bar"];
```

If you're going to change your string frequently consider using its mutable variant - `NSMutableString` which allows to append strings without creating new instance:

```
NSMutableString *mutString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"foo"];
[mutString appendString:@"bar"];
```